# Selenium php-webdriver ignores all the arguments and extensions

Tags: php, selenium, facebook-php-webdriver

**UPDATED**: I will leave the question open in case someone can explain what I was doing wrong. I didn't fix the issue, but I achieved result after switching from "selenium-hub + chrome node" to "standalone chrome" image in `docker-compose.yaml`

---

I'm using [facebook/php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) to run Chrome test with Selenium. Here is the simple code example:

I'm using [SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/) to run Selenium. So `docker-compose.yaml` is like:

```
...
    selenium-hub:
        container_name: selenium-hub
        image: selenium/hub:latest
        ports:
            - "4444:4444"
    chrome:
        container_name: chrome
        image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
        volumes:
            - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
        depends_on:
            - selenium-hub
        environment:
           - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
           - HUB_PORT=4444
           - SCREEN_WIDTH=1280 
           - SCREEN_HEIGHT=800
           - SCREEN_DEPTH=24
        entrypoint: bash -c 'SE_OPTS="-host $$HOSTNAME" /opt/bin/entry_point.sh'
...
```

PHP code:

```php
        $options = (new ChromeOptions())
            ->addArguments([
            '--window-size=640x480',
            ]);
        $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
        $capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
        $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub/', $capabilities, 5000);
        $driver->get('chrome://version/');
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        echo $driver->takeScreenshot();
        $driver->quit();
```

For some reason params in `addArguments()` doesn't have any impact - the outcome is always the same no matter what was set in the method `addArguments()`. It is always something like this

[image]

Whatever I'll put to `addArguments()` nothing will change.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Environment information:

- Php-webdriver version: 1.7.1
- PHP version: 7.2.19
- Selenium server version: 3.141.59
- Operating system: Alpine Linux
- Browser used + version: Chrome 75.0.3770.90
- SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium: 3.141.59

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with Java Selenium tests. After couple of hours I have figured out, why no arguments were passed to chrome. You can try to pass whatever arguments ("aaaaa=bbbbb",...), but no args are passed.

Solution is to upgrade webdriver (not chromedriver). In my Java case, updating version numbers in Maven's POM file of all "org.seleniumhq.selenium" dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the composer update helped! Before these I fixed in the composer.json file to get a version over 1.8
Спасибо помогло обновление composer update! Перед эти исправил в файле composer.json на получение версии более 1.8

```
{
    "require": {
        "php-webdriver/webdriver": ">1.8"
    }
}
```

Установилась версия 1.11

Comment: Please translate in english